# Pandas: drop non-integer data

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have dataset, in which I read the data, `df.dir.value_counts()` returns

```
169      23042
170      22934
168      22873
316      22872
315      22809
171      22731
317      22586
323      22561
318      22530

         ...  
0.069        1
0.167        1
0557         1
0.093        1
1455         1
0.130        1
0.683        1
2211         1
3.714        1
1.093        1
0819         1
0.183        1
0.110        1
2241         1
0.34         1
0.330        1
0.563        1
60+9         1
0.910        1
0.232        1
1410         1
0.490        1
0.107        1
1.257        1
1704         1
0.491        1
1.180        1
5-230        1
1735         1
1.384        1
```

The `dir` column is about direction, and the data should be integer, ranging from (0,361). As you can see, there are a lot of errones data at the end of the `value_counts()` list.

I want to know, how can I drop the non-integer data?

---

There are some possible ways

1.`read_csv` as integer and throw all non-integer data

```
df = pd.read_csv("/data.dat", names = ['time', 'dir'], dtype={'dir': int}})
```

However, there some string like error data, such as `60+9`, which would cause error. I don't know how to handle it.

2.Select by `isdigit()`, and then do a downcast

```
df = df[df['dir'].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]
df['dir']=pd.to_numeric(df['dir'], downcast='integer', errors='coerce')
```

This is from [Drop rows if value in a specific column is not an integer in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499973/drop-rows-if-value-in-a-specific-column-is-not-an-integer-in-pandas-dataframe), and works fine for me, but it feels a little bit too much. I'm wondering if there are better approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like

```
df.dir[df.dir == df.dir // 1]
```

## How It Works

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(dir=[1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]))
print(df)

   dir
0  1.0
1  1.5
2  2.0
3  2.5
```

Anything that is an integer should be equal to itself floor divided by one.

```
df.assign(floor_div=df.dir // 1)

   dir  floor_div
0  1.0        1.0
1  1.5        1.0
2  2.0        2.0
3  2.5        2.0
```

So we can test for when they are equal

```
df.assign(
    floor_div=df.dir // 1,
    is_int=df.dir // 1 == df.dir
)

   dir  floor_div is_int
0  1.0        1.0   True
1  1.5        1.0  False
2  2.0        2.0   True
3  2.5        2.0  False
```

So to filter, we can use the boolean mask in the demo column `'is_int'`

```
df.dir[df.dir == df.dir // 1]

0    1.0
2    2.0
Name: dir, dtype: float64
```

---

If there are strings in this column, then you can incorporate `pd.to_numeric`

```
df.dir = pd.to_numeric(df.dir, 'coerce')
df.dir[df.dir == df.dir // 1]
```

Comment: But there are `string` types in this column, I'm not sure if this is ok for `//`?

Comment: @piRSquared - floor division is nice